# How to create a program that computes standard deviation using iteration and another one that uses recursion both using c programming

Tags: c

How to create a program that computes standard deviation using iteration and another one that uses recursion both using c programming

here's my code for standard deviation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float StandardDeviation(float data[], int n);

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    float data[100];

    printf("Enter number of data( should be less than 100): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter elements: ");

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    scanf("%f",&data[i]);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Standard Deviation = %.2f", StandardDeviation(data,n));

    return 0;
}

float StandardDeviation(float data[], int n)
{
    float mean=0.0, sumDeviation=0.0;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n;++i)
    {
    mean+=data[i];
    }

    mean=mean/n;

    for(i=0; i<n;++i)
    sumDeviation+=(data[i]-mean)*(data[i]-mean);

    return sqrt(sumDeviation/n);
}
```

Comment: What was your question? How to write your `StandardDeviation` recursively?

Comment: This question is kinda weird. With regards to the iterative version - you already seem to have it implemented. With regards to the recursive version - there doesn't seem to be any real need to provide a recursive solution for this specific problem. A recursive solution is helpful when the problem at hand can be decomposed into smaller sub-problems, and the solutions too these sub-problems can be recomposed into the solution of the original problem.

Comment: Agreed. You can turn interation into tail-recursion and vice versa, but that just means tail-recursion is generally a Bad Idea and should be avoided. Unless you specifically need to store and restore state while computing sub-problems, recursion is the wrong answer. (Though from past questions here, some professors are pretty horrible about assigning recursive tasks that should never be written that way.)